# how to sudo jps on aws ec2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sudo

when I try `$ sudo jps` there is only error messages :

**sudo: jps: command not found**

when I not use sudo command, jps works well :

**7762 Jps**

===========

p.s.
my solution is `sudo -E $JAVA_HOME/bin/jps` but that is quite uncomfortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `sudo` modifies PATH and the command `jps` is not found in the modified (root's) path. To preserve path:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" jps
```

or

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```